# How do I know the last document was sent in documentdb?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to develop a 'infinite scroll' like application using `documentdb` as source of data.

Basically when the user loads the website page it gets 5 records and a `continuationToken`, on the client I have a JavaScript array which I concat with these records and display on the website. Then the user scrolls down and I send the next request with the `continuationToken` and get more 5 results until the server sends me everything and the `continuationToken` comes null again and then if the user scrolls down the array will be concat with repeated records infinitely.

I would like to know if there's some way to know that the last record was sent or I need to deal with it on the client?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `if theres some way to know that the last record was sent or i need to deal with it on the client?`. If the response doesn't include a continuation token that would be an indicator that no more documents are available.

Comment: The first request is null too, so after get all documents i will sent a null continuation token and then get everything again, repeatly.

Comment: Like @Aravind mentioned in his comments, you would need to keep a flag indicating if a request must be sent. By default keep its value to true. Then each time you get a response, check if you receive continuation token or not and set its value appropriately (false if no token is received).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only marker from DocumentDB that indicates that there are no more results is a null `continuationToken`. So you have to add logic in the client that when this is null, there are no more results to load.

Comment: Good point, you need to track two flags - one to check that the query was submitted at least one, and another to track the latest continuation token.